# Files deployed in module cannot be found

Tags: 2010, deployment, master-page, module, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to deploy a selection of pages and master pages in modules but I'm encountering the same problem with all of them.

When I try to navigate to a page, I get a File Not Found error (with unfortunately no information in ULS), but when I view the site in Designer, the files are there in the places I expected. In addition, the master pages show up in the Master Pages section of Site Settings, but when I set the master page on my site and navigate to default.aspx, I get file not found errors again.

I can see that the files have been deployed properly, but why are they not being served?

Here's the markup I've got in my module element files:

```
<Module Name="MyWebPages" Url="SitePages">
  <File Path="MyWebPages\Page1.aspx" Url="Page1.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
</Module>
```

and

```
<Module Name="MasterPage" List="116" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
  <File Path="MasterPage\MyMasterPage.master" Url="MyMasterPage.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" />
</Module>
```

**Update** I've redeployed the pages module, which seems to be working now, but still no luck with the master page.

**Update 2** Added the new master page Elements.xml file. The strange thing is that the master page has deployed fine in the past, but I'm now I'm on a new site, it's failing.

**Update 3** Added Falak's suggestions

Comment: First things first: Are you sure you're navigating to the correct page? Try launching the page from designer using the "Preview in Browser" ribbon button, or right-click action.

Comment: I've tried navigating from the the designer, get the same error.

Comment: What do you see if you go to the "MyWebPages" library?

Comment: I've redeployed the web pages module which seems to be working, but no luck with the master pages one. The master page is viewable in /_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx, and I can download it, but any page that uses it shows the cannot be found error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions, the solution turned out to be a bit more involved. The master page I was trying to deploy has code behind in the GAC, and one of the libraries that referenced was missing - hence the "file not found" errors. Unfortunately because of some [logging problems](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72721/sharepoint-errors-not-recorded-in-uls) I've also been having, I couldn't see what file was missing!

For anyone else reading this question, the markup that works for me is that currently displayed in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are missing the content type property in your element file, and possibly more: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bobgerman/archive/2011/01/31/packaging-master-pages-and-page-layouts-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: Also, you may need to approve your new master page. See further down the page I linked.

Comment: Yes, I've tried setting the content type in the element file and in the properties dialog on the site, page is set to approved, still no luck...

Comment: Please update your original post with any changes you made to your elements files.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `List` attribute to `116` i.e. `Master page Gallery`. For Master page you don't need a Content type association. Associate your Content Type with relevant page layouts and use fiddler to check the request. See sample below:

For master pages:

```
      <Module Name="MasterPage" List="116" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" >
        <File Path="MasterPage\MyMasterPage.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" Url="MyMasterPage.master" />         
      </Module>
```

For the page layouts, set the `Url` attribute of module to point to `Master page gallery` and `PublishingAssociatedContentType` and other properties like this:

```
<Module Name="PageLayouts" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
    <File Path="PageLayouts\YourPage.aspx" Url="YourPage.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true">
      <Property Name="Title"
                Value="YourPageName" />
      <Property Name="MasterPageDescription"
                Value="YourPageDescription" />
      <Property Name="ContentType"
                Value="YourContentTypeName" />
      <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage"
                Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLeft.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLeft.png" />
      <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType"
                Value=";#YourContentTypeName;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D00bc6ec9af9289476b99640c668f2c50fc01;#" />
    </File>   
</Module>
```

Note: the content type id being used is inherited from `Article page` [publishing content type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648024.aspx).
Happy SharePointing!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're provisioning your page layouts in a correct way? Can you try my updated code for Page layouts as well?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear in the update, my page layouts are deploying fine.